# Can chicken stock be used as the basis of a savoury loaf?

Tags: bread, chicken, chicken-stock

I have a surplus of jelly like chicken stock. I hope to mix it with flour, baking soda and eggs, with some herbs and spices, to make a savoury loaf.

Comment: So more like soda bread than yeast bread?

Comment: It should be fine, but I would suggest warming it slightly so that it is more liquid, so that volume doesn't exceed the liquid amount in recipe, such as  soda bread as @Stephie asks. It could work well in a sourdough recipe, or in a savory bread pudding.

Comment: I'm very curious to hear how this turns out. The stock is going to add quite a bit of protein, so I'm not sure you need to further enrich it with eggs.

Comment: I did go ahead and attempt the savory loaf.  It needed much less stock than I wanted to use up so from that standpoint it was not a great success.  Nor was it all that enjoyable, though I ate it.  I may have used more stock than needed and the texture was not so nice.